# how to put the error logs in an error log file such as error.log using Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

how come this configuration doesn't log any errors at all inside my log folder

```
'log' => array(
    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
    'routes' => array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
            'categories'=>'system.*',
            'logPath'=> '/export/home/sasori/branch/logs/',
            'logFile'=>'error.log',
        ),
         array(
             'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
             'levels'=>'info',
             //'categories'=>'application.*',
            'showInFireBug'=>true
         ),
    ),
```

OR THIS

```
'log' => array(
    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
    'routes' => array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
            'categories'=>'system.*',//'application.*',
            'logPath'=> '/export/home/sasori/branch/logs/',
            'logFile'=>'error.log',
        )
    ),
```

I also changed the error.log file's permission to 0777 ,but it didn't help at all

Answer (score 2):

There are hardly calls to `Yii::log()` in Yii's core. Most are `Yii::trace()` which you'll only see if you have set `YII_DEBUG` true and add log level `trace`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's still the case in current Yii 1.1.13.

Answer (score 0):

I also confuse about the Yii log system. In my project, logs are seperated by categories and will be kept in corresponding folders. But log system not works fine. Sometime yii wouldn't wrote log, and sometimes log config will cause an error saying 'unvalid path...'

```
'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
                'categories'=>'application',
            ),
            //where problem occures
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
                'logFile' => date('Ymd').'.log',
                //'logPath' => '../../logs/se',
                'logPath' => 'logs/se',
                'categories' => 'se.*',
            )
        ),
    ),
```

Any one has any idea about why?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the 'categories' as array with categories, maybe it will helped

```
array(
        'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
        'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
        // Change categories as array
        'categories'=> array(
            'system.*'
         ),
        'logPath'=> '/export/home/sasori/branch/logs/',
        'logFile'=>'error.log',
    ),
```